# Inserting joined records. The true way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Please tell me the elegant way to save records into the two joined tables.
I have three tables (models):

- The **products** table has fields: `id`, `name`, `sizes`
- The **images** table has fields: `id`, `name`, `file_path`
- The **images_products** table has fields: `product_id`, `image_id`, `position`
- The `position` field in the table "**images_products**" means ordinal number

Here we go.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :description, :presence => true

  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

  has_many :product_images
  has_many :images, through: :product_images
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_images
  has_many :images, through: :product_images

  #  attr_accessor :position
  #  def position
  #    product_images.position
  #    p "Test Position"
  #  end

  def file_path
    "sofas/imgs/" + super
  end
end
```

And the join table:

```
class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "images_products"
  belongs_to :image
  belongs_to :product
end
```

I expected something like this:

```
pr = Product.new
imgs = Images.find(params[:checked_images][ids])
pr.images = imgs
# It's should not work, I know. But I don't know right way.
pr.images[0].product_image.position = 0
# or something like:
pr.images[0].position = 0
```

Maybe there is way to map "*position*" field of the table "**images_products**" through the **Image** model. Well, I confused.

Comment: Its all about http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question. I'd personally do something along the lines of...

```
@product.images.build(image_params)
@product.save
```

In the controller.